# Bookmark using Part in article

Tags: bookmarks, parts

Since I started using Part in my article, the bookmarks in my pdf have been screwed up.

I now have the bibliography and the appendix as subsections of the final Part of my article. I want these sections to be outside of part, at the highest level within the bookmark-tree. =

I also want to add a bookmark for the cover-page and the content-page at this same level, above the first Part in the tree.

Comment: Are you using only one part? Bibliography makes use of `\section*{}`. Also appendix. So they are unnumbered sections.

Comment: Several parts, as in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `bookmark` package and issue `startatroot` at the appropriate spot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\begin{document}
\part{First}
\section{One}
x
\section{Two}
y

\part{Second}
\section{Three}
x
\section{Four}
y

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{x} Something
\end{thebibliography}

\appendix

\section{App}
z
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works, although strange it wouldn't do that automatically.